# Nose Tests - File Uploads

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylons, nosetests

How would one go about testing a Pylons controller (using Nose Tests) that takes a file upload as a POST parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
class TestUploadController(TestController):
    // ....
    def test_upload_files(self):
        """ Check that upload of text file works. """

        files = [("Filedata", "filename.txt", "contents of the file")]
        res = self.app.post("/my/upload/path", upload_files = files)
```

Uploading file usually requires authenticated user so you may also need to pass "extra_environ" argument to self.app.post() to circumvent that.

See [paste.fixture documentation](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/fixture.html) for details on the arguments accepted by self.app.post()